# Query for Counting number of orders by UK postcode

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, count

I have got a table of orders placed by customer , what i want is to check from which part of the country orders are coming historically, I can only check this by postcodes , for intance an order with post code SK... means its stockport , similarly the post code starting from M .. means the order is from manchester, Is it possible to write a query which can count the orders  by postcode.

Some of the fields of the Order table:
OrderNumber  OGUID custID firstname last name address postcode email authorisation date etc...

Any suggestion or assistance will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: You'll probably need to find some sort of mapping between postcodes and place names - without horrible string parsing I guess you'll need to try and find a third party on the web who has already done this and will provide you with a SQL table to partially match against. I don't expect this will be free! Here's one I've found for example, but it costs £24 : http://www.sqldumpster.com/databases/geographic/30-uk-towns-cities-postcodes.html

Answer (score 1):

If you have a table that contains the city code and city name, then you might be able to use something like the following which joins your `orders` table to the codes using a `LIKE`:

```
select o.postcode,
  c.city,
  count(c.code) over(partition by c.code) Total
from orders o
inner join codes c
  on o.postcode like '%'+c.code+'%'
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3a233/3)

<strike>You can use `GROUP BY` to get the total number of orders in each `postcode`:</strike>

```
select postcode, count(postcode) TotalOrdersByPostCode
from orders
group by postcode
```

If you want the `City` included, then you can also `GROUP BY` city:

```
select city, postcode, count(postcode) TotalOrdersByPostCode
from orders
group by  city, postcode
```

Comment: all post codes are different apart from the city code , i want to count orders by post code but it should be grouped by city

Comment: @MrA you can add a grouping by city as well

Comment: i think you misunderstood my question , for instance if i got 3 orders one from M8 5CA , SK 1SED , M9 6AU , the query should return : Manchester 2 orders , Stockport 1 order , as M in the postcode represents Manchester and SK in the postcode represent Stockport

Comment: @MrA do you have some sort of table that will identify each of the cities and the city/postcode?  If not, then how are you going to determine if one postcode starts with one letter or two?

Comment: yeh i got a list of all the uk cities with their codes , but its quite huge

Comment: @MrA see my edit, you are joining to probably have to join your list of cities and the code to your orders table.

Comment: yep I can see that , i dont have city code column in my db :(

Answer (score 1):

Here is way that works... but it can get too long for a huge list. I will try to find a way around that problem.

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN postcode LIKE 'SK%'   THEN 'SK'
    WHEN postcode LIKE 'M%' THEN 'M'
  END AS group_by_value
, COUNT(*) AS group_by_count
FROM [Table] a
GROUP BY 
  CASE
    WHEN postcode LIKE 'SK%'   THEN 'SK'
    WHEN postcode LIKE 'M%' THEN 'M'
  END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(1) over(partition by postcode) as countByPostcode, othecolumnhere
from Order
```

Comment: wat do u mean by other column

Comment: i mean you can add any other colum there as you wish, like 'OrderNumber OGUID custID firstname last name address'

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this? The town part of the postcode will be the first 1 or 2 bytes, delimited by a number after, I think. So this will give you the first few letters.

```
select substring(postcode,1, patindex('%[0-9]%',postcode)-1), count(*)
from Order
group by substring(postcode,1, patindex('%[0-9]%',postcode)-1)
```

Then you'll have to decode M into Manchester, W into West London, GU into Guildford etc...